# History table for datachange in a tablerows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a history table with the following fields,

```
ColumnName,OldValue,NewValue
```

Now I am updating `table X` and I want to update my history table for the list of field values I changed. How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Please post your current query and what your current approach to this is and explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server 2008 or later, you can use the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) & [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) commands. Here are a few links that should

- [MERGE and OUTPUT – the swiss army knife of T-SQL](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2010/01/06/merge-and-output-the-swiss-army-knife-of-t-sql.aspx)
- [MSDN: OUTPUT Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)
- [MSDN: MERGE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Alternatively, you could use the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) command only (doesn't require SQL Server 2008 or later) in conjunction with your delete/update statements to move the data around with a single statement.